# Placing UIProgressBar on UIToolbar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ios5

[image]

Hey guys, when I drag a `UIProgressBar` right to the middle of the `UIToolbar` interface builder just rejects it. Is it possible to place a progress bar on the toolbar? It would be pretty convenient in my use case if I could find a workaround. Thanks.

Comment: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:DABStKYu6V8J:www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/88328-mail-style-uiprogressview-on-uitoolbar.html+UIProgressBar+on+UIToolbar&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=safari

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding UIProgressBar Programmatically on UIToolbar , that should work i guess.
Let me know the results...